# SignalR or NodeJS/Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, compare, socket.io, signalr

I want to develop a real-time application with C# and MVC3. I used Socket.IO in several projects but now, I see some good news about SignalR and some guys says that SignalR could be a good alternative for Socket.IO...

I want to know is there any problem or bugs with SingalR and is this a good choice to move from Socket.IO to SignalR?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of using SignalR in your case is it's a complete client-side and server-side solution with JS on client and ASP.NET on the back end.

But you can see their are some opened issues: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues